# ASP.net How to handle login/logout with role based access

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, login-control, role-base-authorization

**Scenario:** I have the membership provider setup and its currently pointing to a SQL database on my machine. The role based access works and I have a menu that is security trimmed. The user can only get to pages that they have access to.

**Problem:** When an anonymous user tries to get to a page that they dont have access to it brings them to a login page so that they can login. That is fine. But when a logged in user tries to get to a page they dont have access to(Usually by typing in a URL) it brings them to the login page again asking them to login(except there already logged in. I'd like to either take them to a different page or somehow tell them they don't have access. Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2010/01/12/redirect-unauthorized-users-to-access-denied-page-instead-of-login-page.aspx) is what I use. They point out that using `<customErrors>` won't work because of the way the 401 status gets changed and provide a solution.

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm. I will upvote tomorrow, at my limit at the moment lol.